# Why is there still a "this could be a duplicate" box after ticking "No it's not"

Tags: bug

I've asked [a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636759/why-does-parseint-warn-of-using-valueof), it has no close votes and by now a score of 40. Someone commented that the question could be a duplicate and I've been shown a yellow box with a link to the question and a selection saying something like "It's not a duplicate, I will edit".

I then edited the question and clarified why it can't be a duplicate, but I'm still shown the following box:

[image]

Shouldn't this box be hidden after a question doesn't get any duplicate votes, and the OP clicked the "No it's not.." text and edited the question?

Comment: It might be that after you hit that option, someone else flagged the question. It would have to be flags, as a comment by itself does not trigger that box. However, my guess is just that: A guess. I have zero proof that this is what it is, but it makes sense.

Comment: Note, in case you're not aware, that only you see the banner. Still, it does seem like it should go away if you've responded to it.

Comment: Yeah, If I only I can see it, it makes even more sense to remove it after I've responded. @JoshCaswell

Comment: @Michael Looks like valid duplicate to me (but I know nothing of Java)... It is generally good idea to edit post with something like "the *{suggested duplicate link}* discusses similar issue, but it does not cover ... / looks at different aspect of ...." so everyone sees why it is not duplicate and at the same time question shows additional research after close votes aged out/obsolete "could be dup" comments removed. Your [current edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44636759/3) will look very awkward if comment with possible duplicate link removed.

Comment: Just stating that the duplicate didn't work without explaining why isn't enough either. The why very well could point out the key difference between the two, or even better the root of your actual problem.